# Having difficulty saving image to Firebase and then getting image path

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, firebase-storage

I'm working on a blog in React and saving everything in MongoDB. I have an `article` array with each article having a `title`, `content`, `author` and `imagePath`.

```
const articleSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    author: { type: String, ref: "User", required: true },
    placement: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["featured", "card", "stories"],
      default: "stories",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Everything is wrapped up inside a form, including the image so when the user hits the submit button it publishes. When the user publishes the article, the image gets saved to firebase.

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

const imagePath = uploadBytes(imageRef, image).then((snapshot) => {
    getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
      console.log(url);
    });
  });

<Form.Group className="my-2" controlId="content">
  <label>Image</label>
  <input
    type="file"
    placeholder="Image"
    onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
  ></input>
</Form.Group>
```

Everything works perfectly fine. The article gets published and the image gets saved to Firebase. When I `console.log(imagePath)` I get the correct path. When I try saving that to the `submitHandler` I get an undefined object saved inside my MongoDB instead of the actual image path.

```
 try {
   const res = await write({
     title,
     content,
     username,
     placement,
     image: toString(imagePath),
   }).unwrap();
   navigate("/");
   toast.success("Article Added!");
 } catch (err) {
   toast.error(err?.data?.message || err.error);
 }
};

MONGODB
_id: 657d70d8af9322a9df1b72be
title: "rhtrth"
content: "rthrth"
image: "[object Undefined]" // imagePath saved as undefined
author: "Dagger"
placement: "featured"
```

I'm wondering how exactly can I save the image path of my uploaded image inside my MongoDB so when I use loop through the data inside the `SingleArticle` page:

```
<img src={article.image} alt="" fill className={styles.image} />
```

... it will display the proper image.